# VMWare ESXi 4.1 refuses to keep permissions for Domain Groups

Tags: active-directory, vmware-esxi

<strike>I just set up a Windows Small Business Server 2011 Essentials server in my environment.  I have a VMWare ESXi 4.1 host running standalone that I am able to have join the domain.</strike>

When I right click the Host, and choose Add Permissions, and set the Administrator role for one of my Domain users or groups in vSphere Client, as soon as I click ok, the role is lost.  Trying to authenticate with the domain credentials in vSpere client says "You must use a user name and password" (paraphrasing).

I can't, for the life of me, figure out how to have the roles be retained.

Here is a new wrinkle to this problem.  The permission **are** working, but the vSphere client does not pass them through when you check "Use Windows session credentials" if i enter `domainname\username` with the domain password, AD authentication works successfully

Answer (score 2):

Have you created an AD group named "ESX Admins" and added the relevant AD users to that group? It's my understanding that that's what's needed on the AD side.

Comment: haven't they removed that requirement in 4.1?

Comment: It's in the v4.1 'Configuration Guide'.

Comment: The server configuration documentation doesn't specify (that I could find), but this document seems to be saying that it is needed: http://blogs.vmware.com/esxi/2011/01/esxi-41-active-directory-integration.html

Comment: http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1025569

Comment: So my understanding of that is that the functionallity still exists, but isn't required?

Comment: yep, I don't use it and domain based delegation of roles works fine.

Comment: @joeqwerty: I tried this, and it still did not help my issue

Comment: This was not the problem at all